# Turbo Delphi & Reports

Tags: delphi, report

Is there a way to use reports in **turbo Delphi**, I searched a lot for Report components, but I couldn't find any !

any hint is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

You mean you have a paid version, not the free "explorer" versions?  There are lots of reporting options.

Report Manager is an open source solution you can use:
http://reportman.sourceforge.net/

There are lots of other reporting solutions for Delphi, most of them commercial (e.g., FastReport, ReportBuilder, Rave Reports, Quick Reports, etc.).

Rave reports may have a free version available for your TurboDelphi.  For example, for TurboDelphi2006 you can look here:
http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/25610

Here's a list of various reporting tools from the Torry's site.  Take note that many of them are old and/or not that great.  It's probably best to stick with the better-known components:
http://www.torry.ru/pages.php?id=189

If you do have only the free TurboDelphi "Explorer" then your options are more limited.  Since you  can't interface to components at design-time,  only through code, I think the visual report designers in most of the commercial versions will be unavailable to you.  That makes them a lot harder to use.  The good news:  I think the open source ReportManager has a stand-alone visual report designer that lets you design and save report definitions.  That would be the way to go.  It may still be a little cumbersome to use, since you'll have to instantiate all report components at runtime.